# cloud functions python to access Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

I am looking for a tutorial or document on how to access datastore using cloud functions (python).

However, it seems there is only tutorial for nodejs.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/functions/datastore
Can anybody help me out?
Thanks

Comment: Use the general documentation on accessing Cloud Datastore from Python. I recommend you use the Cloud Client Libraries as documented here (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write to Google Cloud Storage from Cloud Function (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249978/write-to-google-cloud-storage-from-cloud-function-python)

Answer (score 2):

There are no special setup needed to access datastore from cloud functions in python.

You just need to add `google-cloud-datastore` into `requirements.txt` and use datastore client as usual.

## requirements.txt

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
google-cloud-datastore==1.8.0
```

## main.py

```
from google.cloud import datastore
datastore_client = datastore.Client()

def foo(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values...
    """
    query = datastore_client.query(kind=<KindName>)
    data = query.fetch()

    for e in data:
        print(e)
```

## Read more:

- [Python Client for Google Cloud Datastore](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/index.html)
- [Setting Up Authentication for Server to Server Production Applications](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)