# Write to Google Cloud Storage from Cloud Function (python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I am trying to upload a file to google cloud storage from within a cloud function.  I can't import the cloud storage library into my function, though.

Can cloud storage be used from within cloud functions in this manner?

### Cloud Function

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, blob_text, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_string(blob_text)

    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))

def log_data(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket'
    BLOB_NAME = 'test-blob'
    BLOB_STR = '{"blob": "some json"}'

    upload_blob(BUCKET_NAME, BLOB_STR, BLOB_NAME)
    return f'Success!'
```

### Error

```
Deployment failure:
Function load error: Code in file main.py can't be loaded.
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from google.cloud import storage
ImportError: cannot import name 'storage' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

Comment: Did you add google.cloud (google-cloud-storage) to your requirements?  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime#specifying_dependencies

Comment: Sorry but how do you test this sort of parameterised functions in Cloud Functions ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to add the [`google-cloud-storage`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/) package to your `requirements.txt` file to install it in the Cloud Functions environment.

Comment: thanks for the answer it did solve my problem too but how do you test this sort of multi parameterised functions in Cloud Functions

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you ask a new question with more details?

Comment: Asked here, thanks - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65148708/testing-a-cloud-function-from-trigerring-event-option