# Testing a Cloud Function from Trigerring Event option

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

so I have this sort of http cloud function (python 3.7)

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, blob_text, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_string(blob_text)

    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))
```

Now I want to test this function from Testing tab of the Functions details page where it asks for triggering event in JSON format.

i tried with various formats like

```
{
    "name":[param1,param2,param3]
}
```

but always ended up getting error

```
upload_blob() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'blob_text' and 'destination_blob_name'
```

Also tried to find out any documentation but was unable to do so, can you help in pointing to the right direction

Comment: Which version of GCP do you have in your requirements.txt?

Comment: The run time is Python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `upload_blob` function doesn't look like an HTTP Cloud Function. HTTP Cloud Functions take a single parameter, `request`. For example:

```py
def hello_http(request):
    ...
```

See https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#writing_http_helloworld-python for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Dustin you should add an entry point which parses the json request.

A code snipped for the following request will be as follows:

```
{"bucket_name": "xyz", "blob_text": "abcdfg", "destination_blob_name": "sample.txt"}
```

The entry function will be as follows:

```
entry_point_function(request):
   {
   content_type = request.headers['content-type']

   if 'application/json' in content_type:
      request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
      
      if request_json and 'bucket_name' in request_json:
        text = request_json['bucket_name']
      else:
        raise ValueError("JSON is invalid, or missing a 'bucket_name' property")
   }
```

Rename the entry point in the function configuration. For the cloud UI
[image]

You need to change